# set a different height for the bootstrap fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using bootstrap for my portfolio, and i want the fixed navbar to have a height of 150px.
Anyways, I can't figure out how to do this.

Is there anybody here who knows how to do that ?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you'll need to add it to your CSS like this:

```
    .navbar {
        height: 150px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, but not the best, is by adding a `style` attribute to your `navbar` `div` in which you set `height` to `150px`, like so:

`<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="height: 150px;">`

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this

```
   .navbar {
        height: 150px;
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Aea8P/)

Comment: I make demo in this minutes when I read question it haven't answers ))